# Html: Fix space in text field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to fix a space in a text field value. Means when text field appear there is a space on it already and user enter value after the space. And also user is unable to remove that space, when he/she erase its value. I know this thing can be done by padding, but i have an issue and want a fix space in value.

```
<input type="text" id="search" value="fix space" />
```

Text Field: (fix space)user value

Comment: So you want a textbox that already has a space as a prefix and can never be removed?

Comment: Yes like (space)input

Comment: `I know this thing can be done by padding` then what is the issue ?

Comment: "but i have an issue". What is that "issue"?

Comment: Although you don't want a padding solution, it is still the "best" solution. You can just add a space to the input value in javascript

Comment: Basically i have a font issue (NafeesNastaleeq.woff) which can't be removed from padding. If you write from direction rtl.

Comment: @Guillaume ...or if possible even better on server side.

Comment: @MTA if issue is rtl direction font then you can set `padding-right:10px;` to your textbox

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone indeed, my point being that css is the way to go here

Comment: I have already tried right padding but the issue is with the font it is for ltr direction, so if i write in rtl direction first character is half removed and can come only by space at the start

Comment: Can you provide a running (static) demo on https://jsfiddle.net/ reproducing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a keyup event to check for a space and add it if need be:

```
<input id="mytb" type="text" onkeyup="addSpace()" />

function addSpace() {
    var tbVal = $('#mytb').val();
    if (tbVal.substring(0, 1) != ' ') $('#mytb').val(' ' + tbVal);
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you don't want a jquery solution, I recommend using @Tushar solution

Comment: nm. you are Tushar.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use keyup or blur events:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (this.value.indexOf(' ') != 0) {
    this.value = ' ' + this.value;
  }
}, false);
```

Or :

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      if (this.value.indexOf(' ') != 0) {
        this.value = ' ' + this.value;
      }
    }, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm, css is the way to go but from the sounds of it, you want the space to be part of the data that gets submitted.

If this is the case, why not prefix the space in the submit handler?

Comment: Please share some code or solution. Otherwise use comment section for comment purpose.!

Answer (score -1):

I think you want a space to be prefixed in front to the user input.
If that is only for visual effects you have to make changes in CSS like below.

```
input{
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

If you want an actual space character to be included you can use the Javascript below to add a space before the users input when the form is submitted.

```
function DoSubmit(){
  var elem = document.myform.search.value;
  document.myform.search.value = ' '+elem;
  return true;
}
```